# Как взаимодействуют серверное java-приложение и клиентское FLEX-проиложение?

Tags: java, apache-flex

Вопрос, собственно, в заголовке.
Предположим, есть сервер, на нём приложение, реализованное на java. Есть БД MySQL. Есть клиентское приложение, реализованное на FLEX. 
Каким образом они взаимодействуют друг с  ругом? (Кроме данных из БД) Т.е. как клиент знает о результате сервера? Посредством каких механизмов?

Answer (score 2):

Можно запросить нужные данные по HTTP в виде XML или JSON. Можно использовать веб-сервисы, например, REST или более старомодный SOAP.

Answer (score 2):

True-way для Flex+Java, на данный момент, теоретически, это **BlazeDC** от Adobe. Технология позволяет пересылать объекты между java сервером и flex клиентом подобно SOAP, но в отличие от последнего и ему подобных XML форматов, использует бинарный формат AMF, что существенно экономит траффик. Технология открытая и бесплатная.